# Why doesn't my application run after I obfuscate it when I reference other projects?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am working on obfuscating a Windows Phone App.  If I obfuscate just the application project on its own, everything seems to work fine.
However, I am trying to reference a third party graphing library.  The library is another project inside my solution.  If I reference that project, build a new package and then obfuscate it, the app crashes as soon as you hit any code that uses the third party library.  Both assemblies are strongly signed.
I have tried various things in Dotfuscator.  If I include both DLL's under the "input" tab but don't apply any obfuscation to the external library DLL, it doesn't work.  If I exclude the library from the dotfuscator project entirely and obfuscate just the app itself, the app doesn't even run.  I have both set to re-sign on build using the right key.

Any ideas?  I don't understand why if I do nothing to the library DLL it still crashes just because it was part of the Dotfuscator project.

Comment: Perhaps the graphing library accesses some of its own properties by reflection somewhere in a static initializer?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203453/workaround-for-reflection-bug-in-dotfuscator

Comment: I am not obfuscating any of the code inside the graphing library so that should not have any effect.