# Groovy c# expression eqivalent to evaluate property

Tags: groovy

In .NET we could write code like the following to return the propertyName

```
public static string GetName(Expression<Func<object>> exp)
{
    MemberExpression body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (body == null) {
        UnaryExpression ubody = (UnaryExpression)exp.Body;
        body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }

     return body.Member.Name;
 }

 public class Test
 {
     public string prop1 { get; set; }
 }
```

Inside of properties, we usually use OnPropertyChanged(() => this.prop1) which would return the propertyName. For more info, see this post([How to raise PropertyChanged event without using string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191536/how-to-raise-propertychanged-event-without-using-string-name))

I want to do something simular in groovy, but I am not sure the right way to do this.

```
    class TestObj
    {
        def prop1 = "value" 
        def prop2 = "value"
    }

    class Test{
        def something(){
            def t1 = new TestObj()
            def propertyName1 = getName{ t1.prop1 }
            def propertyName2 = getName{ t1.prop2 }

            assert propertyName1 == "prop1"
            assert propertyName2 == "prop2"
        }
    }
```

How would you implment the getName method in groovy using an expression as seen above

Comment: Is this an interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come to delivering this capability feels completely contrived and kludgy and *ad hoc* to me. It relies on the Java Bean API, facilitated by the Groovy `@Vetoable` annotation to keep most of the ugliness *outside* the class code:

```
import groovy.beans.Vetoable

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException

class TestObj {
    @Vetoable def prop1 = "value"
    @Vetoable def prop2 = "value"
}

def t1 = new TestObj()
def getName(def t, Closure c) {
    def name
    t.vetoableChange = { PropertyChangeEvent pce ->
        if (!pce.newValue) { throw new PropertyVetoException("", pce) }
    }
    try { c.call() }
    catch (PropertyVetoException e) { name = e.propertyChangeEvent.propertyName }
    t.vetoableChange = { it -> }
    name
}
def propertyName1 = getName(t1) { t1.prop1 = null }
def propertyName2 = getName(t1) { t1.prop2 = null }

assert propertyName1 == "prop1"
assert propertyName2 == "prop2"
```

YUK!

Answer (score 0):

To me the most beneficial use of such a method would be at compile time, so that this kinda code breaks as early as possible and simple string-typos won't lead to bugs at runtime.  In a highly dynamic language like groovy there is hardly a way to get a proper method reference to work with.  So here is some code, that does this **at runtime** but the only thing you get out of this is an assert (in the code below), that you are controlling. (`clazz.&something` is not a real method reference like you would get with e.g. `Clazz::getSomething` in java8 or c++).  So here is some clunky attempt to abuse the `MethodClosure` and do a trivial check, if the owning class has a getter for this **at runtime**.

```
class Clazz {
    String username
    String firstName
    def lastName
    String getFake() { return 'fake' }
    void setSomething(String something) {}
}

String getName(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure it) { 
    def m = it.method.toString()
    assert it.delegate.respondsTo("get${m[0].toUpperCase()}${m[1..-1]}")
    it.method.toString()
}

def c = new Clazz()
assert getName(c.&username) == 'username'
assert getName(c.&lastName) == 'lastName'
assert getName(c.&fake) == 'fake'
```

That said, what I have seen in the code examples, this whole technique seems to me to help the developer on the side of *firing* the events to prevent errors with mistyped strings.  So there might be an even groovyier solution to all of this by just using [`@Bindable`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/beans/Bindable.html), which turns your properties or all properties of a class into "bound properties according to the JavaBeans spec".  This generates the whole property change boiler plate code for you resulting in alot less code to worry about.

Comment: It seems that you could get a false positive with this approach if there is a method `Clazz.getWhatever(String stuff)`. In this case the method takes an argument and hence does not represent a property. However `assert getName(c.&whatever) == 'whatever'` still passes. Maybe an additional assertion inside the `getName()` method, say `assert it.parameterTypes.size() == 0`, would be in order

Comment: @BalRog yeah one could also check the properties of the owner/delegate, if there is something there, which might even be easier after all, but needs a find{}

Comment: True dat. One more possible bug here. I haven't checked for sure but I think that if the property name is a single character the subexpression `${m[1..-1]}` will throw some sort of "index out of bounds" exception. In the past I have had to use something ungainly like `${m[1..<m.size()]}` to get around this problem.

Comment: @BalRog or in short: as yuk as ;)